# Double wrapfigure on the same paragraph

Tags: wrapfigure

I am trying to add two images, one on the left and one to the right, in a wrapfigure manner. I would like it to look like that

[image]

Although my code works for the sirst image, I don't know why it isn't working for the second one. My code is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext}

\begin{document} 

\begin{wrapfigure}[12]{l}{0.32\textwidth}
    \vspace{-0.6cm}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pixel}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
Αυτός ο ανιχνευτής τροχιών χρησιμοποιείται για να μετρήσει και να καταγράψει τις τροχιές των σωματιδίων της δέσμης με μεγάλη ακρίβεια. Είναι κατασκευασμένος από έξι επίπεδα από αισθητήρες πυριτίου, παρόμοιους με τις κάμερες που διαθέτουν τα κινητά μας τηλέφωνα. Κάθε αισθητήρας αποτελείται από μικρές ψηφίδες(\eng{pixels}) με μέγεθος περίπου μισής ανθρώπινης τρίχας, με τις οποίες προσδιορίζεται η θέση του εκάστοτε σωματιδίου. Όπως ακριβώς το φως δίνει ένα σήμα στην κάμερα του κινητού μας τηλεφώνου, έτσι και τα σωματίδια δίνουν ένα σήμα σε αυτούς τους αισθητήρες. Συνδυάζοντας τις συντεταγμένες της θέσης από την οποία προήλθε το κάθε σήμα για τους έξι ανιχνευτές, μπορούμε να υπολογίσουμε με ακρίβεια την τροχιά του σωματιδίου. Το τηλεσκόπιο μπορεί να χρησιμοποιηθεί είτε ως ένας ανιχνευτής τροχιών ή ως ένα εργαλείο με το οποίο θα δοκιμαστεί ένας άλλος ανιχνευτής τροχιών. 
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.32\textwidth}
    %vspace{-0.6cm}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{tracker}
        \caption{(Πηγή:\eng{DESY})}
        \label{fig:tracker}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
Στo σχ. \ref{fig:tracker} οι ανιχνευτές τροχιών απειονίζονται με μπλε χρώμα ενώ ο υπό δοκιμή ανιχνευτής με κόκκινο.Μετά τον υπολογισμό της διαδρομής των σωματιδίων στους έξι ανιχνευτές του τηλεσκοπίου, η σύγκριση με την μέτρηση του υπό δοκιμή ανιχνευτή θα δείξει με πόση ακρίβεια μπορεί να μετρήσει.

\end{document}
```

My output is

[image]

What is done wrong here?

**EDIT**

If I add some more code I get this terrible result

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Τηλεσκόπιο ψηφίδας έξι επιπέδων}

\begin{wrapfigure}[12]{l}{0.32\textwidth}
    \vspace{-0.6cm}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pixel}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
Αυτός ο ανιχνευτής τροχιών χρησιμοποιείται για να μετρήσει και να καταγράψει τις τροχιές των σωματιδίων της δέσμης με μεγάλη ακρίβεια. Είναι κατασκευασμένος από έξι επίπεδα από αισθητήρες πυριτίου, παρόμοιους με τις κάμερες που διαθέτουν τα κινητά μας τηλέφωνα. Κάθε αισθητήρας αποτελείται από μικρές ψηφίδες(\eng{pixels}) με μέγεθος περίπου μισής ανθρώπινης τρίχας, με τις οποίες προσδιορίζεται η θέση του εκάστοτε σωματιδίου. Όπως ακριβώς το φως δίνει ένα σήμα στην κάμερα του κινητού μας τηλεφώνου, έτσι και τα σωματίδια δίνουν ένα σήμα σε αυτούς τους αισθητήρες. Συνδυάζοντας τις συντεταγμένες της θέσης από την οποία προήλθε το κάθε σήμα για τους έξι ανιχνευτές, μπορούμε να υπολογίσουμε με ακρίβεια την τροχιά του σωματιδίου. Το τηλεσκόπιο μπορεί να χρησιμοποιηθεί είτε ως ένας ανιχνευτής τροχιών ή ως ένα εργαλείο με το οποίο θα δοκιμαστεί ένας άλλος ανιχνευτής τροχιών. 
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.32\textwidth}
    %\vspace{-4cm}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{tracker}
        \caption{(Πηγή:\eng{DESY})}
        \label{fig:tracker}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
Στo σχ. \ref{fig:tracker} οι ανιχνευτές τροχιών απειονίζονται με μπλε χρώμα ενώ ο υπό δοκιμή ανιχνευτής με κόκκινο.Μετά τον υπολογισμό της διαδρομής των σωματιδίων στους έξι ανιχνευτές του τηλεσκοπίου, η σύγκριση με την μέτρηση του υπό δοκιμή ανιχνευτή θα δείξει με πόση ακρίβεια μπορεί να μετρήσει.

\subsubsection*{Θερμιδόμετρο Κρυσταλλικού Μολύβδου}

{Καλορίμετρο είναι ένας ανιχνευτής ο οποίος μετρά τις ενέργειες και τις θέσεις των προσπίπτοντων σωματιδίων. Για παράδειγμα, ένα ηλεκτρόνιο θα δημιουργήσει έναν ηλεκτρομαγνητικό καταιγισμό, εναποθέτοντας όλη του την ενέργεια, επιτρέποντας με αυτόν τον τρόπο μια ακριβή μέτρησή της. Τα πιο βαριά σωματίδια θα δημιουργήσουν και αυτά σήμα αλλά η ενέργεια που εναποθέτουν είναι σημαντικά μικρότερη από αυτήν των ηλεκτρονίων. Μετρώντας αυτήν την ενέργεια, τα σήματα που έχουν προέλθει από ηλεκτρόνια μπορούν να διαχωριστούν από τα αντίστοιχα των μιονίων, καονίων, πιονίων ή πρωτονίων. Παρά το γεγονός ότι μπορούν να χρησιμοποιηθούν σαν ανιχνευτές θέσης, ο προσδιορισμός είναι λιγότερος ακριβής.}

\subsubsection*{Ανιχνευτής ((Καλαμάκι)) τεσσάρων επιπέδων}

Αυτός ο ανιχνευτής τροχιών αποτελείται από μεταλλικούς κυλίνδρους( ((καλαμάκια)) ) οι οποίοι είναι γειωμένοι ενώ ανάμεσά τους υπάρχει αέριο. Στο κέντρο του κάθε κυλίνδρου υπάρχει ένα λεπτό μεταλλικό σύρμα, το οποίο βρίσκεται σε υψηλό δυναμικό. Αν ένα φορτισμένο σωματίδιο διαπεράσει τον κύλινδρο, θα ιονίσει το αέριο και ηλεκτρόνια θα κινηθούν προς το θετικό δυναμικό όπου θα δημιουργήσουν ένα σήμα. Ο αριθμός των συρμάτων καθώς και ο χρόνος ολίσθησης από το πέρασμα του σωματιδίου μέχρι τον χρόνο άφιξης του σήματος, θα οδηγήσει σε μια ακριβή μέτρηση της θέσης. Τα τέσσερα επίπεδα επιτρέπουν  μια ακριβή μέτρηση της τροχιάς του σωματιδίου.

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: in the first example, it looks like the text is really set as two paragraphs -- observe the short line at the bottom of the first picture.  finding a similarly appropriate place to break the text of the second example could be a possible approach, but i don't spot anything really attractive along that line.  possibly following the "me" (the next-to-last word on the last line next to the first picture), and forcing that line to extend flush right (with a temporary `\parfillskip=0pt`) and starting the next line as a new paragraph with `\noindent` could bear fruit as a hack.

Comment: Create a paragraph break between "journey" and "The telescope" and it will work as you expect. And read wrapfig manual about its limitations. I recall it mentioning something like that.

Comment: @Thanos: Re your edit: try first with minimal parameters to wrapfig - start with `{r}{0pt}` and `{l}{0pt}` and work from there. I am having a hardest time compiling your examples as they don't work for me w/o importing graphicx package, but simply speaking, your parameters seem to be wrong.