# Wrapfloat and tikzpicture problem

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a problem with tikzpicture inside the environment "wrapfloat". The code works well for the first tikz picture, but for the second and the following figure, the text doesn't wrap the figure. This is my code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openright,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{amssymb, graphicx, pgfplots, wrapfig}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=newest,standard/.style={
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    enlarge x limits=0.1,
    enlarge y limits=0.15,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of       origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=north east}
}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns, shapes, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\begin{document}
\section{Risalire all'equazione di una curva partendo dal grafico}
\begin{wrapfloat}{figure}{i}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[standard,
ytick={1,2}, yticklabels={$1$,$2$}, xtick={-1}, xticklabels={$-1$},
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,width=6cm, height=6cm,
xmin=-3, 
xmax= 3, 
ymin=-1, 
ymax=3]
\addplot [domain=-4:4,samples=700,smooth] {(x+1)^2+1};
\draw [dashed] (-1,0)--(-1,1);
\draw [dashed] (0,1)--(-1,1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfloat}
\textbf{text} text

text text text \\
\begin{wrapfloat}{figure}{i}{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[standard,
ytick={0,0}, yticklabels={$O$}, xtick={0,0}, xticklabels={$O$},
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,width=9cm, height=9cm,
xmin=-7, 
xmax= 7, 
ymin=-3, 
ymax=7]
\addplot [domain=-5:5,samples=700,smooth] {0.3*(x)^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5,samples=700,smooth, green] {0.3*(x)^2+3};
\addplot [domain=-5:5,samples=700,smooth, red] {0.3*(x)^2-3};
\draw [->] (0.5,1)--(0.5,2.5);
\draw [->] (0.5,-0.8)--(0.5,-2.3);
\node [] at (1.2,1.7) {$\tiny{+m}$};
\node [] at (1.2,-1.7) {$\tiny{-m}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfloat}
\noindent text text\\
\begin{wrapfloat}{figure}{i}{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[standard,
ytick={0,0}, yticklabels={$O$}, xtick={0,0}, xticklabels={$O$},
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,width=9cm, height=9cm,
xmin=-12, 
xmax= 12, 
ymin=-3, 
ymax=7]
\addplot [domain=-12:12,samples=700,smooth] {0.3*(x)^2};
\addplot [domain=-12:12,samples=700,smooth, green] {0.3*(x+6)^2};
\addplot [domain=-12:12,samples=700,smooth, red] {0.3*(x-6)^2};
\draw [->] (0.5,1)--(0.5,2.5);
\draw [->] (0.5,-0.8)--(0.5,-2.3);
\node [] at (1.2,1.7) {$\tiny{+m}$};
\node [] at (1.2,-1.7) {$\tiny{-m}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfloat}


\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The text should be after \wrapfloat (which starts a new paragraph).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Do you want to answer?

Comment: @cfr - Do I hafta?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Do you have to want to answer? Of course not. Do you have to answer? Ditto. Maybe it is a dupe?

Comment: It's related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148389/double-wrapfigure-on-the-same-paragraph?s=2|1.0163, which alas doesn't have an answer either.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97871/wrapping-images-in-text-without-inducing-ugly-justified-text was much more useful.